# user presence in android im APP?

Tags: android, push-notification, xmpp, rabbitmq

I have an instant messaging app for android where users can chat. it is done by a rabbitmq server. Messaging just works fine. I need to find out the user presence whether user is online or whats the last online time. some how i think xmpp can do it but i'm not sure how to this.

Any ideas how to find the user presence in mobile IM apps ?

Thanks,
Seshu

Comment: I'm also really interested in a solution, did you find something ?